# Same binary & different permissions, How can it be?

Tags: linux, permissions, process, gdb, elf

I was doing a pwn ctf and found a weird situation.

The ctf includes binary file and a server.
There is a given elf 64 bit.

checksec output (same local & server).

```
Arch:     amd64-64-little
RELRO:    Partial RELRO
Stack:    No canary found
NX:       NX disabled
PIE:      No PIE (0x400000)
RWX:      Has RWX segments
```

From here we can understand that there are RWX segments and there is no NX bit. While running the program with gdb (locally) I could see that the only segment is RWX is my stack.

```
0x00000000401000 0x00000000000000 r-x [executable]
0x00000000602000 0x00000000001000 r-- [executable]
0x00000000603000 0x00000000002000 rw- [executable]
0x00000000624000 0x00000000000000 rw- [heap]
0x007ffff7d89000 0x00000000000000 rw-
0x007ffff7db1000 0x00000000000000 r-- [libc] 
0x007ffffffff000 0x00000000000000 rwx [stack]
```

I finished the ctf while overkilling solution and then I checked some writeups to see if I did as others.

Then I saw that others used other segments as RWX segments, I used my own exploitation and checked server perms.

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 103:00 23593680  [executable]
00601000-00602000 r-xp 00001000 103:00 23593680  [executable]
00602000-00603000 rwxp 00002000 103:00 23593680  [executable]
00603000-00624000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0  [stack]
```

I did a md5sum on the binaries and they are the same. readelf says the only segment is rwx is the stack (as locally).

How could it be?

Comment: I mean, were they allowed to modify the memory image of the running process? not hard to interfere with the point where they protect these segments.

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, the pwn challenge doesn't include mprotect or things like this, it's just a simple binary.

Comment: well, so load that binary in a debugger, and prevent it from setting the protections?

Comment: what do you mean? while debugging locally I get no rwx segments but the stack, on server it's different.

Comment: I might simply have no bigger picture of what you're doing, but if you are the one executing an executable, you can do *anything* you want to its process memory before and while it's being run without modifying the executable file on storage.

Comment: Let me explain better, the challenge gives you the binary so you can reverse it and the server running the same binary, locally I can edit whatever I want but it won't help me finding the exploit on the binary, I need the find exploitation on the binary as it is so I can run the exploit on the server too, while running the binary locally I get different page permissions than running it on server, same binary same md5.

Comment: ah, the only logical conclusion then is that the environment the binary runs in on the server is different than your locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148054/discussion-between-ori-and-marcus-muller).